# Alter row color every x rows on a HTML table

Tags: html, css

As the question title says, I would like to alter the row colors in a table every x rows.
Not every row, but *every x rows*.

Just for the sake of explaining, this is what it could look like when altering every 2 rows: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dreamonic/1nyzwnqp/)**

The HTML is just a regular table, something like this:

```
<table>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>more content</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

In the example I'm using a class for the `tr`'s that should be marked, but I want a more generic way, possibly making use of the `nth-child` selector or something along that way.

Does anybody know of a simple way to do this, possibly with a variable number of altering rows (e.g. every 2 rows, 3 rows, 4 rows,... )? As said, I would like to avoid adding class names because the table would probably be dynamically generated and thus I am most likely not able to alter that code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set colours using nth-child like this:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

For more than 2 different options, you use the formula (an + b) where a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value. Here, we specify a background color for all tr elements whose index is a multiple of 3:

```
tr:nth-child(3n+0) {background:#999;}
tr:nth-child(3n+1) {background:#CCC;}
tr:nth-child(3n+2) {background:#FFF;}
```

Comment: I was going to accept the answer of @CoryCarter , but after your edit I feel like this answer is more complete. The explanation is a big part of what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're right with `nth-child`. Just think in multiples/groups of 4:

```
tr:nth-child(4n+1), tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background-color: yellow;
    /* possibly other styles */
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly what suits my needs, but I feel that @entreprenerds answer has better explanation about how to achieve the desired result. Thank you for the very fast answer nevertheless!

Answer (score 3):

**Example of the above code**

```
tr:nth-child(4n+1), tr:nth-child(4n+2) { 
    background-color: gray;
}
```

`4n+1` with `n = 0`: 4 * 0 + 1 = 1
`4n+1` with `n = 1`: 4 * 1 + 1 = 5
`4n+1` with `n = 2`: 4 * 2 + 1 = 9
`4n+1` with `n = 3`: 4 * 3 + 1 = 13
`4n+1` with `n = 4`: 4 * 4 + 1 = 17
`4n+1` with `n = 5`: 4 * 5 + 1 = 21

The same counts for `4n+2`:

`4n+2` with `n = 0`: 4 * 0 + 2 = 2
`4n+2` with `n = 1`: 4 * 1 + 2 = 6
`4n+2` with `n = 2`: 4 * 2 + 2 = 10
`4n+2` with `n = 3`: 4 * 3 + 2 = 14
`4n+2` with `n = 4`: 4 * 4 + 2 = 18
`4n+2` with `n = 5`: 4 * 5 + 2 = 22

Note: `n` always starts at `0` by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression for the `nth-child` of tr as shown below:

```
tr:nth-child(an+b) {    //a and b can be changed to your requirement
    background-color: #AAA;
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/visvam07/1nyzwnqp/4/)